# ¿Cómo puedo contar cantidad de palabras en un archivo .txt en ruby?

Tags: ruby

Resulta que necesito saber cuantas palabras tiene un archivo de texto, ya lo abrí correctamente y probe con el método `length`, pero me arroja la cantidad de líneas del archivo.

Intenté hacerle un `gsub` a la variable que almacena el archivo pero me arroja error.

Pensé en probar con `count`, pero aún estoy viendo cómo se hace.

Comment: Creo que esto te puede dar una idea de como lograr lo que quieres: [contar la frecuencia de una palabra dada en el archivo de texto en Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43671493/8933039)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lo complicado es cómo identificas una palabra, pues puede variar dependiendo tu objeto, idioma, contexto, etc. Una forma simple (pero no perfecta) puede ser: *una palabra es todo texto que está entre dos espacios (espacio, cambio de línea, tab, etc.)*.

Para la definición anterior entonces podrías hacer algo así:

```
File.read(nombre_de_archivo)   # lee el contenido del archivo 
    .split(/[[:space:]]/)      # divide el texto en palabras y crea un arreglo
    .reject(&:empty?)          # elimina los elementos del arreglo sin texto
    .size                      # cuenta los elementos (palabras) del arreglo
```

Archivo ejemplo (prueba.txt):

```
Uno, dos, tres
cuatro, cinco, seis
siete, ocho y nueve
```

- Se agregó un espacio al final de cada línea para entender el uso de `reject(&:empty?)`.

Ejecución paso a paso:

```
File.read("prueba.txt")      #=> "Uno, dos, tres \n" + "cuatro, cinco, seis \n" + "siete, ocho y nueve\n"
    .split(/[[:space:]]/)    #=> ["Uno,", "dos,", "tres", "", "cuatro,", "cinco,", "seis", "", "siete,", "ocho", "y", "nueve"]
    .reject(&:empty?)        #=> ["Uno,", "dos,", "tres", "cuatro,", "cinco,", "seis", "siete,", "ocho", "y", "nueve"]
    .size                    #=> 10
```